# Overlapping in d3

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js

I have created a Gantt chart using d3. My chart contains rectangles of different sizes according to the data. There are overlapping rectangles as well in the graph. I want to ad a functionality so that when the rectangles are overlapping, rectangles with smaller height should be on the top of rectangles with larger height. I am not sure how to do it. It would be great if anyone can help me.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqY5b/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

   <title></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var w = 500;
    var h = 300;
    var padding = 30;
    var rectH = 50;
    var rectW = 100;
    var dataset = [
                    [5, 20, 20, 10, "red"], [480, 90, 20, 10, "red"], [475, 90, 30, 10, "green"], [100, 33, 20, 10, "red"], [330, 95, 20, 10, "red"],
                    [410, 12, 20, 10, "red"], [475, 44, 20, 10, "red"], [25, 67, 20, 10, "red"], [80, 21, 10, 20, "red"], [85, 21, 20, 10, "blue"],
                    [600, 150, 20, 10, "red"]
    ];

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d[0]; })])
                         .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d[1]; })])
                         .range([h - padding, padding]);

    var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                         .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) { return d[1]; })])
                         .range([2, 5]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(xScale)
                      .orient("bottom")
                      .ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(yScale)
                      .orient("left")
                      .ticks(5);

    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    var g = svg.append("g");

    g.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", function (d) {
           return xScale(d[0]);
       })
       .attr("y", function (d) {
           return yScale(d[1]);
       })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return d[2]; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return d[3]; })
    .attr("fill", function (d) { return d[4]; });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want that when those two rectangles are overlapping then a rectangle with smaller height should be on the top of the another one. So I want that the red rectangle should be on the top of blue and for another overlapping I want red rectangle to be on the top of green one.

Thanks

Comment: D3 problems are near impossible to solve without at least *some* code and maybe even a fiddle. You're going to have to post a little more information to get good help

Comment: Hi @JimBeam I have provided the fiddle now. Thanks

Comment: Can you include the code in the quesion, in addition to the fiddle?

Comment: @AnubianNoob I have included the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions:

1) The simplest solution (not what you asked for) is to make the rects translucent; then the underlying rects will show through. In css, add the following

```
rect { opacity: .5;}
```

2) Fundamentally, the order of the rects in the DOM determines which rects are on top. The later rects are displayed over the earlier rects. So, to have the small rects on top, you need to sort the data to have the shorter rects at the end of the series. In your script, add the following right after the dataset is declared.

```
dataset.sort( function( a, b) { return b[2]-a[2]})
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/flintobrien/dxrU8/) a fiddle with both options together.